# Need confirmation of Views being double loaded in iOS14

Tags: swiftui

I believe I have found a possible cause of Views loading twice, would someone please try this to see if they get the same results?  We are trying to determine if it's a bug or a new expected behavior of SwiftUI. (Yes, I understand Beta versions have bugs, but I would have though they would have caught this by Beta 3 unless it's by design)

Point 1: The code below on iOS 13.6 will load views once from the NavigationLink when compiled from Xcode 11.6

Point 2: The same code loads the view from NavigationLink twice on iOS 14.

Point 3: It makes no difference if the code is compiled in Xcode Beta 3 or Xcode 11.6, either compile base will cause the views to load twice from NavigationLink on iOS 14.

Point 4: The loading twice behavior only happens when called from the NavigationLink

OS is Big Sur Beta 3

This is causing our app to retrieve network data twice and doubling our load on the server.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(){
                NavigationLink( destination: DetailView()){
                    Text("DetailView")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
     var body: some View {
           VStack {
               logView("View loaded")
               Text("Hello, world!")
           }
       }
       
       func logView( _ message: String) -> AnyView {
           print("\(message)")
           return AnyView(EmptyView())
       }
}
```

Comment: The problem with the issue us it causes onAppear() to load twice too. That means we can only load data from init() to prevent the double network accesss. Loading Data from init() eliminated the double loading, but it causes every item in a list to load its network data, a larger load than the double onAppear() because users don't click on every item in a list.

Comment: We also learned that the double loading doesn't happen from NavigationLink if its stand-alone and not in a list. So the combination of list/navigationLink and iOS 14 is causing the Views to double load. Seems like a small bug with a large impact. It was difficult to track down because the form looks fine because it double loads so fast. We only caught it from our server testing.

Comment: Submit feedback to Apple, it is still beta so there is chance that it will be fixed till release.

Comment: I submitted that onAppear was loading twice for every View during the first Beta, no response and no fix. I submitted this issue today, we will see if they respond. I submitted here because the responses are better.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in iOS 14 Beta 3, thank goodness!